# To use BottomNavigationView in another class, i.e., not in MainActivity.kt

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragments

I don't know much about Java, Kotlin, and Android. I need to create a BottomNavigationView in AddFragment class (related to fragment_user_data.xml). Is this possible?
The codes I'm trying to include in an app are:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {          
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super. onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_user_data)

    val firstFragment = FirstFragment()
    val secondFragment = SecondFragment()
    val thirdFragment = ThirdFragment()

    setCurrentFragment(firstFragment)

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
      when(it.itemId) {
        R.id.miHome -> setCurrentFragment(firstFragment)
        R.id.miMessages -> setCurrentFragment(secondFragment)
        R.id.miProfile -> setCurrentFragment(thirdFragment)
      }
      true
    }
   }

 private fun setCurrentFragment(fragment: Fragment) =
 supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
   replace(R.id.flFragment, fragment)
   commit()
 }
}
```

My AddFragment class already contains:

```
class AddFragment : Fragment() {

  override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
   ): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_data, container, false)

    mUserViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel::class.java)

    view.add_btn.setOnClickListener {
        func_1()
    }

    return view
  }

  private fun func_1() {

  }

  private fun func_2() {

  }

}
```

Comment: there is a library to do that. Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it.

Comment: there is a whole serie about this component in the official android youtube channel. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fiQiMy0HzsY&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9VpBMZUS9geQtc5RJ2RsUd